# Ran into "ERROR ITMS-90707: "The binary you uploaded was invalid.” when uploading to App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

So I ran into this issue a few days ago and couldn't find a solution based on everyone's responses. When uploading to App Store Connect, you get back this non-useful error message "Error ITMS-90168: “The binary you uploaded was invalid.”

The error log doesn't show where the issue might be and I tried resetting all of my certs, changed computers, revoked certs, etc. Literally nothing works and I can't upload any new builds. Old ones seem to work though so maybe it's my code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because I had changed a few values in my info.plist - Make sure when changing values such as within `Icon files (iOS 5)` (the `UIPrerenderedIcon` value was my issue) that the correct type is set. I had something that was suppose to be a Bool, was a String. Completely breaks the .ipa and you can't upload, but you can build and run. Very weird.